# How to Set UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle if use "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:" method

Tags: ios

Before, I use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`: method, and then i must check `cell` nil:

```
if(!cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
}
```

So i can set style for cell.
But, in new method: "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:" i don't need check cell nil, so how to set style for cell, now? Please help me. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out:

```
cell = [cell initWithStyle: forReuseIdentifier:];
```

I think so, but, has anyone for other answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in your cell property of your storyboard file like this

[image]

Or you can set the table style when you initialize the table view (see initWithFrame:style:). Just remember, you cannot modify the style thereafter.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't use StoryBoard, i wanna use code, and i don't wanna init cell again =((

Comment: I update my answer in case you want to set it programmatically